# How to execute recurring Bash script at specific times?

Tags: bash, scripting, cron, at

How would I set a script to execute on every Tuesday and Thursday at 11:50am?

I've been looking at the `at` command, but I can't conceive how to use it the way I need to from its `man` page.

Comment: Depending on your intit system, you could also use a `systemd.timer`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`at` is excellent tool for one-off commands.  To run a program repetitively at the same times, however, the right tool is `cron`.  Run `crontab -e`.  It will open an editor.  Add this line and save the file:

```
50 11 * * 2,4 /path/to/script
```

This will run `/path/to/script` every Tuesday and Thursday at 11:50am.  `crontab` runs programs in a limited environment.  So, `script` may need to set its own `PATH`, etc.

If the machine has a properly set up mail server, any output from `script` will be e-mailed to the user who owns the `crontab` file.  Alternatively, output will be mailed to the address specified by the MAILTO variable in the crontab file.  See `man 5 crontab` for details.

The first five columns of the line above define the time that the program is run.  Their meaning is documented in `man 5 crontab` to be:

> ```
>           field          allowed values
>           -----          --------------
>           minute         0-59
>           hour           0-23
>           day of month   1-31
>           month          1-12 (or names, see below)
>           day of week    0-7 (0 or 7 is Sun, or use names)
> ```